# How to use XMLNode.SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="VirtualPrintFeesGPAddin.Properties.Settings.GPConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=CONSULTING118\SVR2008A;Initial Catalog=TWO;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

How do I use xmlnode.SelectSingleNode to retrieve the connectionString= value?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VirtualPrintFeesGPAddin.Properties.Settings.GPConnectionString"].ConnectionString;`?

Comment: I'm building a VS Tools for Dynamics GP Add-in which I have read that it "does not have automatic configuration file support". So at runtime Properties.Settings.Default.GPConnectionString yields the string from the dev machine and not the updated config file deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you had that xml in a xmldocument object it would be:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXML("<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name=\"VirtualPrintFeesGPAddin.Properties.Settings.GPConnectionString\"
            connectionString=\"Data Source=CONSULTING118\SVR2008A;Initial Catalog=TWO;Integrated Security=True\"
            providerName=\"System.Data.SqlClient\" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>");

String str = doc.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='VirtualPrintFeesGPAddin.Properties.Settings.GPConnectionString']").Attributes["connectionString"].Value;
```

if you're going to get more that just that one attribute:

```
XmlNode n = doc.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='VirtualPrintFeesGPAddin.Properties.Settings.GPConnectionString']");

String str = n.Attributes["connectionString"].Value;
```

Comment: I am receiving: Non-invocable member 'System.Xml.XmlNode.Attributes' cannot be used like a method. EDIT: using block quotes instead of parentheses works .Attributes["connectionString"].value

Comment: Updated.  Sorry was freehand typing from memory.

Comment: No apology necessary. We cannot all remember every syntactic element of the whole framework.