# Read text from xml string in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read `Message` value from below xml string. How read it?

```
        <Messages> 
           <Exceptions />  
               <ValidationIssues>
                   <ValidationMessage Message="The Customer Communication requires a value for Search Phone or Email." FriendlyMessage="\" />  
                </ValidationIssues>
         </Messages>"
```

tried

```
 var values = (from element in doc.XPathSelectElements("/Messages/Validationsissues/validationmessage")
                   where element.Attribute("message") != null
                   select (element.Attribute("message").Value));
```

did

Comment: Is XPathSelectElements case sensitive?

Comment: Have you fixed your capitalization? Also, your intention is misleading, shouldn't intent extra after a self closing tag.

Comment: Also, 'ValidationIssues' is spelled different to 'Validationsissues'; there's an extra 's' in the middle.

Comment: Where specifically does this fail?  Does `doc.XPathSelectElements("/Messages/Validationsissues/validationmessage")` find what you expect?  Do the matched elements have a `message` attribute?  Don't just randomly write code and give up when it doesn't work.  Debug it.

Comment: @James123 Could you respond to the questions in the comments and answers on your question. If you have found a solution yourself, please post this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

XPathSelectElements is case-sensitive.  Change `element.Attribute("message")` to `element.Attribute("Message")`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXML("<Messages> 
           <Exceptions />  
               <ValidationIssues>
                   <ValidationMessage Message=\"The Customer Communication requires a value for Search Phone or Email.\" FriendlyMessage=\"\" />  
                </ValidationIssues>
         </Messages>"  );


String str = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Messages/ValidationIssues/ValidationMessage").Attributes["Message"].Value;
```

You can also see my other answer at: [How to use XMLNode.SelectSingleNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613948/how-to-use-xmlnode-selectsinglenode/28614127#28614127)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to do this using an `XDocument` and no XPath but simply selecting the "ValidationIssues" elements as in:

```
class Program
{
    static string my_xml = 
        "<Messages> " +
        "    <Exceptions />" +
        "    <ValidationIssues>" +
        "        <ValidationMessage Message=\"The Customer Communication requires a value for Search Phone or Email.\" FriendlyMessage=\"\\\" />  " +
        "    </ValidationIssues>" +
        "</Messages>";

    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(my_xml, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
        var messages = doc
            .Descendants("ValidationMessage")
            .Where(x => x.Attribute("Message") != null)
            .Select(x => x.Attribute("Message").Value);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, messages));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that XML is case sensitive. XML elements and attributes name need to be mentioned in your XPath using the exact same cases.

If you like XPath, you can also add `Message` attribute checking in the XPath. For example, this XPath only return `ValidationMessage` having XML attribute `Message` :

```
/Messages/ValidationIssues/ValidationMessage[@Message]
```

Another tips, you may prefer casting `XElement` or `XAttribute` to `string` -or to some other possible types- instead of accessing `Value` property. This approach has advantages, for example, you can avoid null reference exception in case the attribute/element not found (never happen in this case because we already validate the attribute existence in the `from`/`where` clause), besides you can possibly get the attribute/element value readily in the suitable data type :

```
var xpath = "/Messages/ValidationIssues/ValidationMessage[@Message]";
var values = (from element in doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath)
              select (string)element.Attribute("message"));
```